# Cron increments minute interval by self

Tags: php, cron

I have some weird thing with cron. My goal is to check new posts of users, and I register cron job for each user. The minimum time unit in cron is minute, but I have to check it as often as possible. So I found solution to register several cron jobs using `sleep`, and check user after each 10 seconds. I used following:

```
$user->register_cron('curl "http://app.dreamasik.com/api/insta/gatherPosts/' . $user->id . '"', '* * * * *');
                    $user->register_cron('curl "http://app.dreamasik.com/api/insta/gatherPosts/' . $user->id . '"', '* * * * * sleep 10');
                    $user->register_cron('curl "http://app.dreamasik.com/api/insta/gatherPosts/' . $user->id . '"', '* * * * * sleep 20');
                    $user->register_cron('curl "http://app.dreamasik.com/api/insta/gatherPosts/' . $user->id . '"', '* * * * * sleep 30');
                    $user->register_cron('curl "http://app.dreamasik.com/api/insta/gatherPosts/' . $user->id . '"', '* * * * * sleep 40');
                    $user->register_cron('curl "http://app.dreamasik.com/api/insta/gatherPosts/' . $user->id . '"', '* * * * * sleep 50');
```

Register cron function:

```
public function register_cron($url, $period = '* * * * *'){
        $output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
        file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output.$period.' '.$url.PHP_EOL);
        exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');
    }
```

When it was just created it appeared in cron panel at look great, as I mentioned. Posts was gathered immediately. But now I found that there is some shift in minute (`*` become `*/22` etc):

```
    */23    *   *   *   *   curl "http://app.dreamasik.com/api/insta/gatherPosts/103"   
    */21    *   *   *   *   sleep 10 curl "http://app.dreamasik.com/api/insta/gatherPosts/103"  
    */24    *   *   *   *   sleep 20 curl "http://app.dreamasik.com/api/insta/gatherPosts/103"  
    */16    *   *   *   *   sleep 30 curl "http://app.dreamasik.com/api/insta/gatherPosts/103"
    */22    *   *   *   *   sleep 40 curl "http://app.dreamasik.com/api/insta/gatherPosts/103"
    */23    *   *   *   *   sleep 50 curl "http://app.dreamasik.com/api/insta/gatherPosts/103"
```

I removed all cron jobs and then registred again, but problem appeared day after.

Comment: You say this occurs every night? Are you sure it's not your host running a script to stop cron abuse? Using cron to schedule something every 10 seconds is not its intended purpose. If you really want to do something like this, can you not create a daemon that will stay running, rather than abusing cron in this way?

Comment: @Phylogenesis I did't know about that, can you give refernce to something which could be alternative?